# is it possible to use style for .net winforms control?

Tags: c#, winforms, styling

Is it possible to use style for .net winform control ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this??

- [Devexpress Winforms Skinning Library](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Skins/)
- [Telerik Winforms RadControls](http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms.aspx)

I'm sure there are quite a few more - from hobbyist hacks to professional libraries. Just ask Mr. Google or [Ms. Bing](http://tinyurl.com/24xw2xz)!

Answer (score 0):

If you mean something like CSS in web applications, I have to say that there is not any built in solution in .net framework, but infragistics introduced it's producut which does exactly CSS in web.